# Voip callerid handling

Tags: voip, sip

I am faced with the following problem. I get calls from my customers thou a voip line. And then i need to ask them who they are and look them up. All of this takes the most time in the phone call so i want to speed that up abit.

Basicly i want something that catches the caller id and sends it to a (web) server. Idealy i would put that at the phone server but that part is outsourced. So my question comes down to: Is there an easy way to do this? I can write my own software but i would like something of a voip client that does this for me since i would like the quick solution.

I searched the internet for a view hours but i am not that familiure with voip technologie so any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any softphones could do it although I do have a hazy memory of another stackoverflow question where someone asked about sending a HTTP request triggered by an incoming SIP call. Unfortunately I can't find the question sorry.

Apart from softphones I do know of at least three ways you could do it on a server and there are probably more.

First there's my own software (doable with a free accounts and open source), sipsorcery.com, where you could receive the SIP call from your provider and in your Ruby dialplan send an HTTP request to your web server to get whatever info you wanted.

Secondly there's tropo.com who also have highly extensible dialplan type functionality and in lots of different languages. Their dialplans support sending HTTP requests.

Finally there's anveo.com who have HTTP tools available in their graphical call flow builder.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be sure to try it in abit.

Answer (score 0):

Open source softphones should be extendable, I know twinkle can be configured with scripts, should be well suited for your personal needs.

If this is something you want to centralize, create a SIP proxy to intercept all calls and do what it needs to. Sailfin is a robust development environment for something like this if you like Java.